# Selenium Browser Not Starting, Process Idling with no effect

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

Code:

bot.py:

```
import time
import utils
import requests
import os

import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from managers.managers import BotManager

from main_socket import sio

class Bot(BotManager):

    def __init__(self, data: object = None) -> None:
        """ The base class's __init__, bootstraps Selenium and some instance properties
    
        @Args:
            host: str - the host to navigate to, e.g., www.domain.com
        """
        
        print(1)
        super().__init__(data["host"])
        print(2)
        
        self.__domain = None
        self.__driver = None
        self.__proxy_ip = None
        print(3)
        # Other Chrome options
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
        options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
        options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
        options.add_argument("--browser-version=119")
        options.add_argument("--verbose")
        print(4)
        options.set_capability("goog:loggingPrefs", {
            'browser': 'ALL',
            'performance': 'ALL',
        })
        print(5)
        options.add_experimental_option("perfLoggingPrefs", {
            "enableNetwork": True,
            "enablePage": True
        })
        print(6)
        options.headless = False
        print(7)
        seleniumwire_options = {
            "proxy": {
                "http": os.getenv("PROXY_URL"),
            },
        }
        print(8)
    
        try:
            if not bool(os.getenv("DEV")):
                print(9)
                self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
                    options=options,
                    seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options,
                    version_main=118,
                )
                print(10)
            else:
                print(11)
                self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
                    options=options,
                )
                print(12)
        except Exception as exception:
            print(f"Browser opening exception: {str(exception)}")
    
        print(13)
    
        self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Performance.enable", {})
        self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Log.enable", {})
    
        utils.prevent_additional_windows(self.driver)
    
        self.driver.get(self.host)  # Access the platform
    
        self.__proxy_ip = self.__get_ip()
    
        self.domain = utils.get_domain(self.host)
    
    
        print(f"Data: {data}")
        
        print(f"Proxy: {self.__proxy_ip}")
    
        print(f"Domain: {self.domain}")
    
            
        # Everything is better dark. No Kink.
        match self.domain:
            case "domain":
                time.sleep(10)  # Decrease load
    
                print("Accepting terms...")
    
                # Try to accept the terms
                utils.accept_domain_terms(self.driver)
    
                print("Dark Mode...")
    
                time.sleep(3)  # Decrease load
                WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="user_information_profile_container"]'))
                ).click()
    
                time.sleep(3)  # Decrease Load
                WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                    (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="userInfoDropdownTextColor userInfoDropdownHighlightColor"]'))
                ).click()
    
                time.sleep(3)  # Decrease Load
                WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="user_information_profile_container"]'))
                ).click()
            case _:
                pass
        
        print("Bot created signal...")
    
        self.bot_created_signal(self.data['session_id'])
    
    
    @sio.event
    def bot_created_signal(self, sid):
        sio.emit('bot_created_signal', {"session_id": self.data['session_id']},  self.data['session_id'])
    
    @property
    def driver(self) -> object:
        return self.__driver
    
    @driver.setter
    def driver(self, driver: object) -> None:
        self.__driver = driver
    
    @property
    def host(self) -> str:
        return self.__host
    
    @host.setter
    def host(self, value: str) -> None:
        self.__host = value
    
    @property
    def domain(self) -> str:
        return self.__domain
    
    @domain.setter
    def domain(self, domain: str) -> None:
        self.__domain = domain
    
    @staticmethod
    def __get_ip() -> str:
        """ Utility function for getting the proxy IP """
    
        try:
            response = requests.get('https://icanhazip.com')
            if response.status_code == 200:
                return response.text.strip()
            else:
                print(f"Failed to fetch IP. HTTP Status Code: {response.status_code}")
        except Exception as exception:
            print(f"Trying to get the Proxy IP triggered this: {exception}")
    
        return '127.0.0.1'
```

main.py:

```
import os
import sys

import eventlet
import redis as r
import logging
import utils
import threading

from dotenv import load_dotenv

from bot import Bot

from eventlet import wsgi
from main_socket import sio, app

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) \> 1 and sys.argv\[1\] in ("-h", "--help"):
        sys.exit(0)

    try:
        Bot({"host": "www.domain.com"})
        print("Bot Created")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception in create_bot: {str(e)}")
    
    # Continue with the main logic
    wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('127.0.0.1', 8080)), app)
```

Problem is the browser is not starting. I don't care about other things, the eventlet server won't run because the code is blocked insite the Bot method. If you try to run this code you'll notice printing 1 to 8, then 11 cause of the DEV env var and that's it. No exception no nothing.

Program to run, instead idles.

command python -m main

Comment: I believe that seleniumwire_options argument is only available when importing seleniumwire.  i.e. from seleniumwire import driver.  You are also setting a ton of chromeoptions there... if you still have problems after importing seleniumwire you should pair those down to only the ones necessary... you can crash chromedriver with the wrong options set.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that eventlet.monkey_patch() patches certain os modules that prevent selenium to run correctly. Fixed it with the following:

```
eventlet.monkey_patch(all=False, os=False, select=True, socket=False, thread=False, time=True)
```